# I can't use an existent variable inside a for loop

Tags: c, for-loop, variables

This code should make a sum of the numbers in the main diagonal of a matrix.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define RIG 2
#define COL 5

void sum(unsigned int a[RIG][COL]);

int main(){
    unsigned int a[RIG][COL] = {{1,2,3,4,5},{6,7,8,9,10}};

    sum(a);
}

void sum(unsigned int a[RIG][COL]){

    unsigned int c = 0;

    unsigned int j = 0;

    if (RIG<=COL){
        int n = RIG;
    }
    else{
        int n = COL;
    }


    for (size_t i=0;i<=n-1;++i){
        c += a[i][j];
        j += 1;

    }


    printf("%d\n", c);

}
```

Output:

```
matrix_sum.c:28:21: error: use of undeclared identifier 'n'
        for (size_t i=0;i<=n-1;++i){
                           ^
1 error generated.
```

I don't get why I can't use the n variable inside the for loop. How can I do that?

Comment: Remove unsigned

Comment: The code - as given - compiles fine for me. I suspect in your zeal to reduce the problem to a [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), you have accidentally lost some vital information. Could you post a little more context code?

Comment: @MohammadMoeinGolchin  nothing change.

Comment: After your edit, `n` is defined at block scope, thus, not visible outside the blocks

Comment: @user3121023 how can I make that variable to be usable in the rest of the code?

Comment: @Laynetus  As far as I know a non-square matrix does not have the main diagonal.:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This

```
if (RIG<=COL){
    int n = RIG;
}
else{
    int n = COL;
}
```

does not scope `n` the way you might think it does. Scoping rules are better explained [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/scope), but in short: `n` exists only within each branch of the if/else block. As such, when you attempt to access `n` in your for-loop later on, it no longer exists!

This is trivially remedied by bringing `n` into scope, e.g.

```
int n = COL;

if (RIG <= COL) {
    n = RIG;
}

for (size_t i = 0; i <= n - 1; ++i) {
    c += a[i][j];
    j += 1;
}
```